# How to setup server to serve authentication with Google Script bound to Google Cloud?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform

I have a script at Google Script which creates Google Drive directories and is to be activated by API calls, but I fail to make API call to it.

I have deployed the script, bound it to Google Cloud, obtained all credentials for the script and service account. Now I stuck at the point when API call to this script gives me the following error:

> Caught exception: json key is missing the type field

```
$scriptId = env('GOOGLE_SCRIPT_ID');
$service = $this->getService();
$request = new \Google_Service_Script_ExecutionRequest();
$request->setFunction('main');
$request->setParameters("fdf");

try {
    $response = $service->scripts->run($scriptId, $request);
    if ($response->getError()) {
        $error = $response->getError()['details'][0];
        printf("Script error message: %s\n", $error['errorMessage']);

        if (array_key_exists('scriptStackTraceElements', $error)) {
            print "Script error stacktrace:\n";
            foreach ($error['scriptStackTraceElements'] as $trace) {
                printf("\t%s: %d\n", $trace['function'], $trace['lineNumber']);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
    echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

What am I missing? Is there a comprehensive tutorial on this topic? I've read Google's manuals on the topic but they don't work much for me to solve the problem.

Comment: This error is caused the the service account file that you are specifying. The flie must be in JSON format containing the K,V  `"type": "service_account"`. Your question does not show your you are specifying the service account. Edit your question to show how,